# Intermediate link "/redirect/" not working in the Experiment

Tags: dxa, experience-optimization, dxa-1.6, experiment

I have included a link(www.google.com) in the content which is part of Experiment; On webpage When i click this link it automatically gets converted to the below url which is fine 
http://{domain}/redirect/?Url=www.http://google.com&data=AXHGFETYUXLKG..

but it display below message on the browser and does not redirect to actual url which is www.google.com

```
No matching Localization found for URL 'http://mydxawebsite.com:92/redirect/'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For such URL to resolve, you have to ensure you have a Publication which maps to the Website root (you don't have to actually publish anything in that Publication, but just have a mapping in Topology Manager so a Localization can be resolved).

Alternatively, you can change the redirect URL prefix in `smarttarget_conf.xml` so it matches the URL path of one of your mapped Publications. You will have to change the `ignore-urls` in the `web.config` accordingly.

Comment: I tried option-2 first, and set trackingRedirectUrl="/us/en/redirect/" in smarttarget_conf.xml of deployer,xo management service,xo query service,sdl content service, website/bin/conf. Also in web.config ingnore-urls value to "us/en/redirect". But still the urls for the published content is pointing to http://{domain}/redirect/ on the webpage. I re-published the content, restarted all services where smarttarget_conf is updated.

Comment: You should only have to change the `smarttarget_conf.xml` used in the Web App.

Comment: Hi Rick; Even I make the change only in Web App unfortunately its not making any impact on the the final url value generated on webpage. In smarttarget_conf.xml I am updating the value for attribute "trackingRedirectUrl". Is this not the right place ?

Comment: Yes, that is the setting I meant. Frankly, I haven't tried it myself and am not a XO expert. I'm hoping an XO expert will weigh in soon. :-)

Comment: Hi Rick ; Thanks for quick reply; I tried option 1. And its trying to fetch  item "redirect" from Publication mapped to website Root and failed DEBUG - Request URL 'http://dev-sdl.mytest.com:92/redirect/?url=http:%2f%2fwww.google.com&data=XBZHFllMS0ZaFB9XWEJTXV0eTg4LRUZdA0oZQEJAGlRbXVFfGW0HKgYCHQJVQUISGQMcG15aG11RGFUTLQwVHUpDSkULRRlRWRNVW1MZH14%3d' maps to Localization [14 ('English')]
INFO  - Item '/redirect/index' not found for Localization '14'
ERROR - Item '/error-404/index' not found for Localization '14'

Comment: Does your `web.config` has an app setting `ignore-urls` set to `/redirect` and an `ExperimentTrackingHandler` configured under `system.webServer/handlers`? This is what the DXA XO Module installer should have done.

Comment: Hi Rick ; sorry my bad i forgot to rollback ignore-url value back to /redirect in web.config. It worked fine after that.

Comment: Option 1 mentioned by Rick worked, Add mapping for the Publication which maps to the website root.